# Can maven create a project from a war file?

Tags: maven, blazeds

I want to create a adobe flex blazeds project. How can I create the project using the blazeds.war as the project template ?

Answer (score 1):

```
war -> maven
```

you can't do that, there's no way maven can guess how the war was produced only by analyzing the result

```
generating a project stub for blazeds
```

that you can do. You can used a defined archetype like this one: http://code.google.com/p/maven-blazeds-spring-archetype/

it will force you to stick to the technology (spring) chosen by the archetype developer, however.